# Every Album Art is the same

Tags: windows-phone-7

I'm making a Music-Player for Windows Phone (c#).
I decided to start the App with Pivot-Pages.
One of them is a list of Albums and there is the Album Art on the left side of the list.
I made a class with the properties:

```
BitmapImage artwork;
Album alb;
```

and i made a viewmodelclass for the binding:

```
ObservableCollection<ViewModelHelper.AlbumHelper> albums = new ObservableCollection<ViewModelHelper.AlbumHelper>();

    public ObservableCollection<ViewModelHelper.AlbumHelper> Albums
    {
        get { return albums; }
    }

    public AlbenViewModel()
    {
        LoadAlbums();
    }

    public void LoadAlbums()
    {
        using (MediaLibrary mediaLib = new MediaLibrary())
        {
            BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();

            foreach (Album alb in mediaLib.Albums)
            {
                if (alb.HasArt == true)
                {
                    bmp.SetSource(alb.GetAlbumArt());
                    albums.Add(new ViewModelHelper.AlbumHelper(bmp, alb));
                }
                else
                {
                    bmp.UriSource = new Uri("/Gesture-Music-Player;component/Images/noArtwork.png", UriKind.Relative);
                    albums.Add(new ViewModelHelper.AlbumHelper(bmp, alb));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

When i execute this, the Album Arts are all the same (Which is the Album Art of the last Album in my collection).
If i remove the if condition, the Album Arts are all the image from the UriSource how it should be.

I don't understand why the last image is set to all the albums.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using only one BitmapImage which you subsequently overwrite every time. That's why you only see the last one.

You should move the creation of the BitmapImage inside the for-loop:

```
foreach (Album alb in mediaLib.Albums)
{
    BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();
    if (alb.HasArt == true)
    {
        bmp.SetSource(alb.GetAlbumArt());
        albums.Add(new ViewModelHelper.AlbumHelper(bmp, alb));
    }
    else
    {
        bmp.UriSource = new Uri("/Gesture-Music-Player;component/Images/noArtwork.png", UriKind.Relative);
        albums.Add(new ViewModelHelper.AlbumHelper(bmp, alb));
    }
}
```